# Unable to use full resolution of P2416D

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, resolution

Dell P2416D (Vendor 10AC, Product A0C3) is 2560x1440, but my Mac OS X (on Macbook Pro Mid 2010 connected via Thunderbolt with Mini Display Port cable) doesn't have corresponding file in /System/Library/Displays/Overrides and when I used the SwitchResX Control application taking values from http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1030957703.pdf after reboot this settings were stated as "invalid":

[image]

P.S.: the https://gist.github.com/adaugherity/7435890 didn't reveal the desired resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I jut had to connect to Display Port instead of HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

Use Display Port connector on the monitor - miniDP to DP cable plugged into Thunderbolt (miniDisplayPort) on Mac solves the problem.